# Passing Two GET variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass two GET variables in javascript But I failed,
this is code

```
<span id="display"></span>
```

here, is my javascript code,

```
var post_id = document.getElementById('post_id').value;
var user_id = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
$('#display').load('ajax.php?post_id&user_id='+post_id+user_id);
```

this code only pass `post_id` i want pass both variables,

Comment: Concatenate the strings correctly: `'ajax.php?post_id=' + post_id + '&user_id=' + user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query string is not formatted correctly. A query string looks like this:

`ajax.php?property1=value1&property1=value2`

Yours looks like:

`ajax.php?post_id&user_id=12` (assuming post_id is 1 and user_id is 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#display').load("ajax.php?post_id=" + post_id + "&user_id=" + user_id);
```